# How can I extract information of one group based on the filtrates of another group in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, tidy

My data frame looks like this but with thousands of entries

```
type <- rep(c("A","B","C"),4)
time <- c(0,0,0,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3)
counts <- c(0,30,15,30,30,10,31,30,8,30,8,0)
df <- data.frame(time,type,counts)
df 

  time type counts
1     0    A      0
2     0    B     30
3     0    C     15
4     1    A     30
5     1    B     30
6     1    C     10
7     2    A     31
8     2    B     30
9     2    C      8
10    3    A     30
11    3    B      8
12    3    C      0
```

**I want at each time point bigger than 0 to extract all the types that have counts==30
and then I want to extract for these types their counts at the next time point.**

I want my data to look like this

```
time type counts time_after  type_after  counts_after
 1    A     30      2            A           30
 1    B     30      2            B           31
 2    B     30      3            B            8
```

Any help or guidance are appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not very elegant but should do the job

```
library(dplyr)

type <- rep(c("A","B","C"),4)
time <- c(0,0,0,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3)
counts <- c(0,30,15,30,30,10,31,30,8,30,8,0)
df <- tibble(time,type,counts)
df 
#> # A tibble: 12 x 3
#>     time type  counts
#>    <dbl> <chr>  <dbl>
#>  1     0 A          0
#>  2     0 B         30
#>  3     0 C         15
#>  4     1 A         30
#>  5     1 B         30
#>  6     1 C         10
#>  7     2 A         31
#>  8     2 B         30
#>  9     2 C          8
#> 10     3 A         30
#> 11     3 B          8
#> 12     3 C          0

thirties <- df %>% 
  filter(counts == 30 & time != 0) %>% 
  mutate(time_after = time + 1)

inner_join(thirties, df, by = c("time_after" = "time",
                                "type" = "type")) %>%
  select(time,
         type = type,
         counts = counts.x,
         time_after,
         type_after = type,
         count_after = counts.y)
#> # A tibble: 3 x 6
#>    time type  counts time_after type_after count_after
#>   <dbl> <chr>  <dbl>      <dbl> <chr>            <dbl>
#> 1     1 A         30          2 A                   31
#> 2     1 B         30          2 B                   30
#> 3     2 B         30          3 B                    8
```

Comment: Very interesting solution mnist! I have upvoted your answer. One question: What does the counts.x and counts.y stand for?

Comment: aaa I think I got, you rename the counts.x to counts! Great